# Bellman ford algorithm-negative source node

Tags: algorithm

Mean while applying the Bellman Ford's algorithm, if there is possibility of relaxing the source node to a value less than zero (with the help of negative weight edges), then can we do so?....that is can we make the cost of source node negative because it will further affect the whole minimum path weight!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean can you initialise the distance to the source node to something less than/not zero...yes the algorithm will still work but practically this doesn't make sense.  You start at the source so there is no distance (positive or negative) to travel to get there.

Comment: I don't think so because if this would so then I would prefer to re-track the same path many time which has resulted into the negative weight of source node and then as a result of which the weight of minimum path would reduce in subsequent traversings, accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a sample graph to illustrate your point?

If the initial distance to the source is negative as stated the algorithm should still work.  If you are talking about edges that circle back to the source node, with negative weights and these edges can be used in a negative cycle, then yes, like any other negative cycle Bellman Ford will report its existence.